# Should date pickers for meetings offer the ability to schedule a meeting for 0 minutes?

Tags: calendar, datetimepicker

For example: The End time picker in outlook and google calendar allow to schedule a meeting/event for 0 minutes.

Is this a real use case? Why would anyone schedule something for 0 mins? Does anyone know the reason why this option is available?

[image]

Comment: For instance, I have a 'meeting' twice a week to water my plant. Zero minutes is by far the most fitting for this purpose.

Comment: @Dan do you list your plant under attendees for that meeting?

Comment: I do this too! I didn't realize it's so common to set zero-minute meetings that are actually tasks—things that don't have to happen at a specific minute. Questions I have: With over a decade to shape user experiences, **Why did Microsoft Outlook fail to get so many of us to use tasks**? Why didn't Outlook convert a zero-minute meeting to a task? Were we just satisficing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I do *now*!

Comment: If you track and handle collisions with transit time range, these are extremely useful.

Comment: Zero makes even more sense given that the granularity is 30 minutes. What length do you think a 5 or 10 minutes meeting should be reserved as?

Comment: Should you be allowed to schedule a meeting for the year 2525?

Comment: @pkr298 October 16, 2525 3:00 PM -- Check to make sure *Voyager* is still leaving the solar system.

Comment: @jwg Outlook doesn't balk at booking a meeting like that. I have a "meeting" in my calendar at work for 20 minutes in the morning to check various intranet sites, simply to reserve a block of time to get it done, adjacent to a 15 minutes meeting with some other people. The *default* is 30 minute periods, but that doesn't mean you are restricted to whole multiples of 30 minutes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use these to automatically trigger programs to run.

Comment: I schedule my tasks as zero minute meetings because if I made them tasks, I wouldn't see them when looking at my calendar, and I also probably wouldn't get them done before the end of the day.

Comment: I personally use this option all the time. I know about tasks, this isn't the same thing. As a user, I frequently find ways to accomplish goals by using features which the developer may not have envisioned being used for that purpose. Taking those features away from me will piss me off.

Comment: @Dan You tell about a *meeting* to water your plant. Isn't it much a *task* ? (simple though)

Comment: @Dan commenting to you because I got the notification (and thus assuming you didn't) from Benj's comment, which appears to have been directed at you, not me. Drawback to a short username. :)

Comment: @Benj yes, it could be a task, but I like to do it as a meeting because it shows up on my calendar, especially on my phone. I can technically dig into the tasks, but I don't use them for anything else, so that would not be very convenient. They really buried the tasks in the phone interface about a year ago, so I don't use them anymore.

Comment: @Dan OK i understand.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you think about exactly what the user is choosing, this makes sense (to allow zero minutes).

What you're really doing is asking two questions of the user:

- What time do you want to schedule this for?
- How much time on your calendar do you want to block off for this?

The answer to the first is the start time.  The answer to the second is either a number of minutes, or an end time - both have valid logic behind them.  But either way, what you're really doing is picking "how long to block off".  If the user does not want to block off *any* time for the meeting, that's a perfectly reasonable choice when thought of this way.

Answer (score 32):

In this case the meeting can act as two things: a reminder to do something that is not constrained by time and a start of something with no clearly defined schedule.

It could also be an oversight; in Glasgow we have ticket machines for rail that default you to buy 0 tickets which is really dumb.

Comment: I have frequently observed people in offices using 0 minute meetings as reminders. They range from the business related "Mr Smith's plane has landed" meaning you can expect him to call after that point to more personal "Remember to buy mom's birthday card!"

Comment: @theotherone - these are **reminders** they book, not **meetings** (through the meeting feature). Why would you make someone book a meeting when what she want is a reminder? The two has many conceptual differences. Isn't it clearly a UX issue that people who wish to have a reminder, book a meeting as a work around for not be able to book a reminder?

Comment: Technically in outlook there are two types of event, appointments and meetings. Though they pretty much behave in the same way except the appointment only has you as a member. Nonetheless your point still stands with appointments, a reminder isn't an appointment.... there though.... there isn't a separate reminder feature. And the appointment feature does just as good a job so.... why not? There is no limit on number of events you can have on your calendar, it tends to be down to individual people to organise their calendar how they like. And if they want to go beyond the manual a bit,so be it

Comment: @Izhaki while true there is and should be a difference that really only leaves three options. a) leave it as is with 0 minute meeting feature b) create separate reminder feature c) rip out 0 min feature and dont create reminder feature. B) would be optimal since it will remove the confusion but if for whatever reason (budget, legacy code, popular opinion, etc.) they cant make a separate reminder feature then I believe A) leaving the 0 minute meetings is better than no reminder feature at all. So to OP, if you can, make a separate reminder area, but if not this is a good alternative.

Comment: Outlook also has **Tasks**. Clearly, this software has been unable to persuade zero-minute-meeting attendees to use tasks, and has failed to simply convert it for us.

Comment: @DasBeasto even if you can split them out, why would I want to have to learn how to use separate meeting and reminder features.  Keeping everything together in a single interface and single calendar is simpler and more convenient than dealing with more than one of them.

Comment: @DanNeely Well in his comment he said "there are too many conceptual differences" which made me think there would be different conceptual features "repeat frequency for reminders, locations for meetings, etc." but of course if it's exactly the same you may choose to keep it together.

Comment: @Izhaki: In google calendar there's no such thing as "meeting" or "reminder" - there's only "events". And IMHO that's a much more powerful and useful UI than separating out meetings from everything else.

Comment: @Izhaki: Why do you wish to arbitrarily limit the usefulness of your UI?  Just because you can't conceive of a reason to use a <1 minute meeting, do you want to restrict all your users from the opportunity?  If so, what *should* be the minimum meeting duration? 1 minute? 5 minutes?  What harm would be prevented by allowing a 0 minute meeting, while defaulting to something else?  What if my team all take vitamin C at noon?  I could setup a meeting for all to get reminded to take their pill at noon, which takes exactly 15 seconds.... With a 0 length meeting -- no problem.

Comment: aye, its the concept of 'meeting' that's ambiguous, hence my answer.

Answer (score 24):

My answer is why not? Software is designed to enable users. Be cautious of making decisions, particularly ones that constrain users in ways you may not consider. There are many reasons why someone might use it: a reminder or a broadcasted note to others... who knows? (some research may find out)

In my experience, removing things like that because you ask (and don't answer) the question, "who would do that?" always leads to complaints. Also, the best software is able to provide utility in ways even the developers didn't see or intend. Scheduling is rife with such cases.

This relates to two maxims I work from:

1. get out of the users' way
2. Know thy users, and you are not thy users.

Comment: The broadcast is a good point, if you have an alarm notification for you only, but you want to advertise an event for everyone with a reminder, this would work.

Comment: Exactly this. Don't make 0 minutes the default, but if a user thinks she a reason to schedule a 0-minute meeting, it's not your job to prevent that.

Comment: Broadcasting a reminder in the form of a meeting requires everyone to accept the meeting. That's busy work for everyone—not exactly a "get out of the user's (*every* user involved) way" solution Instead, the system could elegantly convert a zero-minute meeting to a **task**, which could appear on a calendar as an icon rather than as a block of time, etc.

Comment: True JeromeR but I am speaking of how someone might use a system outside of it's design specs. But the appointment remains in people calendars whether its accepted or not.

Comment: @JeromeR: Also, some systems allow for automatic calendar update, so no user would have to manually accept...  Most tasks don't allow for an attendee list (at least neither Outlook nor OS X Tasks do.)

Comment: @MrWonderful actually, outlook has a feature allowing you to **assign** a task to someone, which works basically the same as inviting them to a meeting.

Comment: @DanHenderson: I don't see that option in my interface, but then again, I'm using Office 2011 for Mac.  Would that still allow for assigning to multiple people?

Comment: @MrWonderful Here's [what it looks like in Outlook 2013 for WIndows](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9k3UP.png), but the functionality was the same in Outlook 2010. And yes, it allows the task to be assigned to multiple people. But I haven't ever done so, and thus I don't know whether the assigned tasks' completion status is shared or separate, i.e., whether or not one assignee completing the task will mark it complete for the other(s), too.

Answer (score 15):

Should a calculator allow you to add zero to a number? My answer: yes. What's the use case? My answer: it doesn't need a use case. You don't remove a capability that "falls out naturally" and requires no effort to provide, just because you can't think why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: Not sure that's always true. It would require little or no effort to allow meetings of negative length, too, but it would clutter the UI, confuse people, and provide one more way that people could make a mistake. "I can't think of a realistic use for that" is exactly why I wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @NathanLong: Then what is the enforced minimum meeting length?  1 minute?  Why not 5, 15 or 30 minutes?  How would you schedule three 15-second meetings all at 13:05?

Comment: @MrWonderful My point was that features aren't free - their very existence has a cost. If you allow something that makes no sense to you, there may be people who have a reason to do it, and for them, it's a feature. But there may also be people who do it by accident - eg, accidentally schedule a 0-minute meeting, and later wonder why that was even an option. For those people, it's a bug.

Comment: @NathanLong The question is though is allowing 0 minute meetings something that requires work to be done or are they just normally there and preventing them that requires work? To say a feature always requires work isn't true when it could be a matter of checking if meeting length is positive versions more then 0 minutes.

Comment: @JoeW The original question is "does this make sense as a feature?" Whether it requires work to implement is only one factor. Suppose we have a weekday input. It's more work to provide a dropdown than a free-form input, and a dropdown prevents people from typing a fictional weekday, which hey, maybe people want to do that for some reason I can't imagine. Absent a real use case, I'm going to do a bit more work and give the user a bit less freedom, because I think it will prevent mistakes and I see no downside. 0-minute meetings may be fine. But "no real use case" can be a good criteria, too.

Comment: @NathanLong I know what the original question but the assumption you made that you are making that allowing it as a feature has a cost is a faulty one. First off Scheduling a zero minute meeting is something that the user has to do on purpose so they would know and understand what they where doing. Second it is something that most likely would be easy from the development side. If there is a "cost" to allowing a zero minute meeting I would wager it is a pretty low value cost.

Comment: @JoeW Every option in a UI has a cost. The user must find the option they want among all the others, and they may misclick. "Is anyone likely to use this?" is a useful question in design. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 13):

Any sort of open-house event might be well-served by this approach: people can accept and have a reminder added *without it blocking out their calendar*.  The event may also have an end criterion that's not defined in terms of time.  For example:

- Title: Birthday Cake
- Location: My desk
- Time 13:00 tomorrow
- Duration: 0 minutes
- Extra info: Come when you like, but when it's gone, it's gone.

To force a minimum meeting time is an unnecessary restriction on your users without helping them, and begs the question "what is the shortest meeting permissible?"  If you set minimum 5 minutes, the next management fad will be a 1-minute meeting, standing up at your desk shouting what you achieved today.

Comment: I get your point, an event may not have a fixed end time. The Duration in that case could be softer, or in more user centered (like " About an hour or so") or maybe you dont even need to specify a duration. But the concept of having something as 0 minutes is not natural. What does 0 minutes mean ? Is there a time like 0 minutes? Does it mean time has frozen? Its ambiguous.

Comment: @db3184 a zero duration may not be natural, but defining a soft duration causes more questions than it answers: does it (by default) mark someone's calendar as busy? For how long? Does it break compatability between systems (not that there's much, but if your phone supports fuzzy meetings and Google calendar doesn't, what happens on sync? And the 2nd sync?) 0 is more intuitive than NaN to a user.

Comment: I would suggest a useful and concrete meaning for "soft duration" vs "hard duration": a hard duration would block out a person's schedule for the entire time, while a soft duration would require that no other event *completely* cover it.  If the sometime is going to be available from 1:01 to 1:29, one may need to ensure that one doesn't schedule a single event from 12:30 to 2:00, but could schedule an event from 12:30 to 1:15 and another from 1:15 to 2:00.  On the other hand, I think 0 minutes has a useful non-soft meaning.  One might have a "meeting" for a group picture which is...

Comment: ...expected to take less than 30 seconds if everyone shows up promptly.  Saying 0 minutes would seem more natural than trying to guess the exact number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## UX is about human centred design...

Seeing as this is a UX form, one would hope that people will work interfaces from user needs, and no the other way around.

## ...which starts from user stories

If you collect user stories during the research/requirements phase, I doubt anyone would like to book a meeting that has no length - obviously if you meet, the meeting will take some time. A meeting with the length of 0 is not a meeting.

## Senseless

You may have stakeholders asking to have reminders on the calendar, but using the event interface is daft - if the user wants a reminder, why would she have to pick the both the same date and time twice? It's senseless.

Comment: In a small window (e.g. mobile) it could be less hassle to access the appointment-setting dialog that the user uses all the time than to find the "alarm" dialog.

Comment: @ChrisH but finding the "alarm" dialog should be *less* hassle than dealing with the extra (unnecessary) form fields. If not, that's definitely an issue that should be tackled, but it's a different issue.

Comment: @JacobRaihle, I agree in principle.  I've seen commonly-used (by me) features reached by: press `menu`, `more settings`, scroll, press `preferences`, then set something minor. If your users are working around this sort of thing by using a different feature, do you (a) redesign the UI so they can't find anything for a while, or (b) accommodate what they're doing.  Hopefully there's a (c) make it nice, but I'm pessimistic. (See also my answer for what *I believe* is a good use case.)

Comment: Any research like collecting user stories is only as good as the questions you ask. If you ask, "What might you use a *meeting* feature for?", of course people won't pre-emptively imagine creative meeting-esque uses of a feature. But that's not a reason to *prevent* creative use of your app. Read the other answers/comments, and you'll see lots of real-life uses of 0-minute meetings, from team reminders to <5 minute joint tasks to "as long as you like" open invites. Why stand in your users' way, just because your research questions barely scraped the surface of how your app might be used?

Comment: Reusing one feature to accomplish two tasks means not only does the user not have to learn to use the second redundant feature, but they don't have their UI cluttered up with something that only offers a marginal improvement. If it could offer, more than a marginal improvement, maybe that improvement could be incorporated into meetings and be useful there.

Comment: @Rick Or, when the user picks a zero-minute meeting, switch the UI to the "add task" view, prepopulated with whatever values are needed to do what would have happened had the user created a zero-minute meeting (alarms, location, etc.).

Comment: In this specific case, if you were the developer who made the decision to remove this ability, and I knew that you had done so, I would go out of my way to contact you and point out what a terrible decision that was. Many is the time I've wished I could contact developers and tell them "Stop it, you're making stupid decisions."

Comment: "UX is about human centred design, which starts from user stories" After the first release, UX is a two way street: user stories dictate future design, but existing design influences user stories.